# PowerBI Comparable to DataStruct

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am more used to programming than clicking button in a tool, but the "Microsoft Language" misses for me some essential tools for working.

I got a Database which has some Old Conventions of a Primary Key Number which is essential for handling the Data. To ensure that the Convention is the right one I want to check every Element of this Colum with a Table/HashMap or something similiar to check if the Element exists in this table and change it then to a linked Value.

Like in a Hashmap...

[ValueColum]Compare to Key --> If True --> [ValueColum]= HashmapKey

I searched the docs and Internet and sadly didnt find a solution, i thought i got one when I found the "Record" tool from Microsoft but this doesnt work since it can't compare the whole datastruct to a Colum, or may i miss there something?

Comment: do you want to loop through every record of the table with some search criteria?

Comment: Yes, so basically i want to check if the Element exists in my "List" and then use the linked pair to replace the value.

In different languages i have structs like hashmaps or so for it, but here i miss this :/